# User defined signal method

Tags: c

I've been following the APUE textbook where they throw in an example of printing a user-defined signal.

```
static void sig_usr(int);
/* one handler for both signals */
int
main(void)
{
    if (signal(SIGUSR1, sig_usr) == SIG_ERR)
        err_sys("can’t catch SIGUSR1");
    if (signal(SIGUSR2, sig_usr) == SIG_ERR)
        err_sys("can’t catch SIGUSR2");
    for ( ; ; )
        pause();
}
static void
sig_usr(int signo)
/* argument is signal number */
{
    if (signo == SIGUSR1)
        printf("received SIGUSR1\n");
    else if (signo == SIGUSR2)
        printf("received SIGUSR2\n");
    else
        err_dump("received signal %d\n", signo);
}
```

Can someone explain where SIGUSR1 and how SIGUSR2 are defined? I understand that the function just waits to catch the appropriate signal before listening for others but I don't understand how it knows which signal code is SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are defined in the header file `signal.h`. You can programmatically send them by using `kill` command.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew I was missing something simple.